# goldbach conjecture - how to include the define start and finish to get output

Tags: c

Can you help me here? I'm a complete newbie and was given this homework using Goldbach Conjecture in C. I tried to research on my own but with no luck finding a similar requirement. I understand how it works but not sure how to code via C Programming or what would be the most efficient way I can do this where I can define a start and finish and have an output like on the example below using C:

```
#define START 700
#define FINISH 1100
```

**Output will show every even number greater than 2 is the sum of two primes:**

```
700 = 17 + 683
702 = 11 + 691
704 = 3  + 701
:
:
1098 = 5 + 1093
1100 = 3 + 1097
```

Any inputs or sample code to start this would really help.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Make a function which checks if a nr. is prime. Decrement your number until you get  a prime, check if the difference between start and prime is also a prime, if not, continue.

Comment: For ex you have 700, you decrement until you reach a prime nr. 683, check difference between those 2 if prime. That is about it.

Comment: What do you need help with? Finding a compiler? Installing it? Compiling a code file? Executing it? Finding a HelloWorld? Editing it to have the defines? Editing it to make ouput between start and finish? Checking for prime or other steps from Leons comment? If you show the code you already have it becomes much easier to judge how much of a complete newbie your are. If you are the total newbie, then what you are asking for is a beginners tutorial on C. That kind of question is however off-topic on StackOverflow. Please take the [tour], read [ask] and find and follow a C tutorial first.